# Angular app and internationalization and localization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization, internationalization, asp.net-web-api2

we have an existing silverlight app which runs in browser + on hardware.

we want to rewrite this app using angular js and html5.

one of the key requirements with new system is support of internationalization and localization. and target countries are usa, brazil, italy for now.

Am new to this area and have lot of basic questions.

1. does existing database needs to be redesigned to support same ? i mean to identify columns (product_name/customer_name etc) that needs to have locale specific data and then store data for each locale and modify sprocs and webapi to accept language parameter and then get content based on that. ?
   I believe we need to user nvarchar for such columns.
2. what will happen to currency and date time columns in db ? say there is quantity column then what should be data type of this column in db ? if current locale is Portuguese then will qty stored in Portuguese number.
3. what is the best practices for storing and retrieving currency column 
   based on locale.
4. what is the best practices for storing and retrieving date column 
   based on locale.
5. how to handle string checks, numeric checks in webapi methods ?
6. how to do comparison and checks in javascript for string,number,datetime

please share link to some good pointers which could help.

so in short right from javascript to .net webapi to database (sql) how should we take care of locale dependent logic and fields

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of questions, let's see if I can answer those.

1. If your existing application is properly internationalized, I don't think there is any need to modify the database. Just make sure it is able to handle international characters (`NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR`, `NTEXT` in MS SQL, valid character encodings in others).
   As for DB design, it is good to keep things locale-independent as long as you can. For instance it is better to store keys in the database and resolve them at runtime. However, if your data is dynamic (i.e. you have product names and their descriptions that changes often), the only way to go is to have translation table and look the data up using valid locale. It's quite complex in relational world (i.e. joins), but it could be done.

2,3. All the numeric columns should be kept locale-independent and formatted on the UI side. The more problematic would be prices and sales orders - you would need an additional column to store the currency code (i.e. 12.34 | USD). On the UI side you would need to pass the code to the Angular currency filter. The only gotcha here is, Angular does not support easy locale context switching, so you would need to use a hacky library like [Angular Dynamic Locale](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale) to load the formats for you.

4. Similar. Keep it locale-independent. DB built-in types should automatically handle that for you and give you nice `DateTime`/`DateTimeOffset` (in a .Net world) back. The only gotcha would be the time zone - it may make sense to use `DATETIMEOFFSET` MS SQL type, as others does not store time zone.
   There is an alternative way to store date and times in the database - you may decide to store it as a number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC - as `BIGINT` type. Especially if you are going to read this directly to JS, you will be able to easily re-create JS Date object (should you need this for calculations or something) in a valid time zone (it works the other way round as well). All you have to do to format date is to use this number (not date, that is AFAIR) and Angular's date filter with UTC as a parameter.
5. I don't think I understand what you're asking exactly. I guess the question is about validation of user input, rather than API. Well, beware of using Regular Expressions, because JavaScript doesn't handle Unicode well (at least in this area). You'd need to ask more precise question.
6. Assuming that you have Number and Date objects (i.e. `typeof o == 'number'`) it is straightforward (as in `obj1 === obj2`).
   As far as strings are concerned... Well, `str1 === str2` will give you valid answer if you want to be exact. If you want to sort them, modern web browsers (Chrome 14+, Firefox 29+, IE11+) implement [EcmaScript 402 Internationalization API](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/index.html) so you can do something like `str1.localeCompare(str2, locale)`, [see this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).
   The real problem occurs when you want to compare two strings case insensitive and accent insensitive for equality (as oppose for ordering like in case of sorting). Basically, there is no way (and this is true even in "big" programming languages like Java or C#).